# how to call custom alert on dialog method of jquery on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a custom popup alert with dialog of jquery.

I have call function on form submit

```
<form name="form" method='post' action="user/purchase_user_tip" onSubmit="validateLogin();">
```

jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validateLogin()
     {
         var session = 1;
         if(session==1)
         {
             $('#dialog').dialog('open');
             return false;
         }
     }
 </script>
```

html dialog

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none"> Some text</div>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: so you want to display the #dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to display the '#dialog' you should consider using this code
    function validateLogin() {
    var session = 1;
    if (session == 1) {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
    }

Comment: do you want to display the #dialog as an alert box?

Comment: why dont you use bootstrap modals it would be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

To make the `#'dialog'` `id` visible use:

```
$('#dialog').show();
```

To hide it again use:

```
$('#dialog').hide();
```

Comment: or just use$("#dialog").toggle();

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the jQuery UI Dialog as it is:

1. declare it (without display none)
2. open when needed

Moreover use the event prevent default and a different function definition:

```js
function validateLogin(obj, e)
{
  var session = 1;
  if(session==1)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen: false});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<form name="form" method='post' action="user/purchase_user_tip" onSubmit="validateLogin(this, event);">
    <input type="submit" value="ClicMe">
    </form>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title"> Some text</div>
```